# Modification jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have next jquery code and i want change `value=""` with `name=""`. How?

```
state.find("option[**value**='" + self.**val()** + "']").show();

    jQuery("#city").on("change", function () {
        var localitate = jQuery("#state");
        var self = jQuery(this);
        state.find("option").hide();
        state.find("option[value='" + self.val() + "']").show();
    }).change();
```

**Update:**

I have

```
<select name="city" id="city">
<option value="ohio" name="1">Ohio</option>
<option value="berna" name="2">Berna</option>
</select>

<select name="state" id="state">
<option name="1">State1</option>
<option name="1">State2</option>
<option name="2">State1</option>
<option name="2">State2</option>
</select>
```

I want use name instead of value for show 2nd select option depends on the 1st select option

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: What do you mean? It seems you just want to change `value` to `name`.

Comment: You want to hide the elements on the second select depending on the value selected on the first? It's that what you want?

Comment: Ok I made an answer, I hope it's what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use something like:

```
jQuery("#city").on("change", function () {
    var state = jQuery("#state");
    state.val("") //Clear the previous selection
    var self = $(this).find("option:selected") //This will be the select so we need to get the selected option from this
    state.find("option").hide();
    state.find("option[name='" + self.attr("name") + "']").show(); //Search them by the name and then show them
}).change();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W39Xj/2/)

Comment: The first option has values like 
<option value="Sibiu" name="41">Sibiu</option> and the second select has values like 
<option value="Craiova" name="1" style="display: none;">Craiova </option> How the relationship will be made for example if i select one option in the first select how the ones on the second select will be filtered in the example if i select Sibiu i get the name 41 but there are no options with value 41 in the second, just 1 and 2

Comment: Exista val 41 in 2nd select. Work in firefox after refresh, but in chrome, all is hide for 2nd select.

Comment: Where is the change script?

Comment: I have not changed anything in code.

Comment: In chrome show only for value = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
state.find('option[name="' + self.attr("name") + '"]').show();
```